# Accessing data of a JSON file in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, array.prototype.map

Hey guys Im trying to make a menu that renders the menu items from this json data.

Im doing this using react so just trying to get the correct syntax around it, here is the data,

```
 {
        "name": "menu",
        "children": [
          {
            "title": "Account",
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "Preferences"
              },
              {
                "name": "Contact Details"
              },
              {
                "name": "Manage Users"
              }
            ]
          },
          

          {
            "title": "Design",
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "Themes"
              },
              {
                "name": "Gallery"
              },
              {
                "name": "Templates"
              }
            ]
          },
```

currently I'm mapping over it and can only get access to the title,

```
 {menu.map((item, i) => (
        <div key={i}>
          <h2>{item.title}</h2>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
```

whats the correct way to get access to the children array within the data so I can then render out the items with an onclick or something ?

cheers

Comment: You need to loop on menu.children. Please check the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use another `.map` function within to map through the children.

```
{menu.map((item, i) => (
  <div key={i}>
    <h2>{item.title}</h2>
    {item.children.map((item, i) => (
      <h4>{item}</h4>
    ))}
  </div>
))}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply call the `children` inside the map, for the example

```
{menu.map((item, i) => (
        <div key={i}>
          <h2>{item.title}</h2>
          {item.children.map(child => <p>{child.name}</p>}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is your updated code

```
{menu.children.map((item, i) => (
    <div key={i}>
      <h2>{item.title}</h2>
     {item.children.map((item, i) => (
       <h4>{item.name}</h4>
     ))}
    </div>
  ))}
</div>}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-dust-po682?file=/src/App.js

Comment: still receiving. Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: check this https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-dust-po682?file=/src/App.js @JamesWuhan

Comment: ok  yes I understand that and have access to the title, but then how do you get access to the "name" sub categories in the children array within it? thanks I will then give you the answer

Comment: @JamesWuhan Hey James, Please mark the answer and vote up. Thanks.